# Switched capacitor inverter

Tags: capacitor, inverter

I am trying to produce negative voltage with this circuit:
[image: the circuit in virtuoso]
[image]

The circuit with PMOS:
[image]
when the parameters are:

```
Vsw=1.1v
vin=1.1v
Cfly=2pF
CL=15pF
Ts=50nS/ f=20MHz
dead time=50pS
```

I can't understand why the output is around -500mV, instead of -Vin.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a clearer and complete schematic. How do you generate gate voltages? They must be non overlapping. And you are mixing numeric evaluation (500mV) with symbolic evaluation (\$V_{in}\$), you might want to be clearer on that side too.

Comment: The schematic is an integral part of your question but the clutter, sideways text, and dark background make it really hard to read. Even just changing the background would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one ugly schematic.

But your main problem is that you have the body connections of M2 and M4 tied to ground. This means that no part of their channels (including the source and drain terminals) can go more than one diode drop below ground.

The body connection of an N-channel MOSFET must go to the most negative potential in the entire circuit in order to keep the implicit (channel isolation) diode reverse-biased at all times.

Also, you're going to have to re-think the gate drive for all of your devices. It would be simpler in many ways if you were to change M1 and M4 to P-channel MOSFETs.

A secondary issue is that the pump capacitor C0 isn't going to charge up to Vin; its voltage will be actually be Vsw minus the threshold voltage of M1, whatever that is. This is another reason to make M1 a P-channel device.

Comment: ...and it happens that a forward biased diode is about 500mV.

Comment: I have edited the pic of the schematic.
when i figure why can't I produce the voltage as I want, I will probably change M1 and M4 to PMOS, but right now it is not whats bothering me.

Comment: Are you having trouble visualizing what happens when M0 turns on and `net04` tries to go negative? Think about what this does to the voltage relationships among all four terminals of M2 and M4 and how they'll behave as a result.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Dave. I don't know how to add a pic to the comment, so I added it(PMOS circuit) to the main question. Still it doesn't work. I am sorry if my questions are ridicules I am newbie in VLSI.

Comment: OK, that's a good start. Now, do you understand that the gates of M1 and M2 in the new diagram need to be switched between DGND and OUT, not DGND and Vsw?

Comment: actually no. Because M2 is NMOS and M1 is a PMOS. I can't understand why they should behave like that.

Comment: Then it's unfortunate that you've chosen a voltage converter as your first design exercise. You do not yet have the background required to complete this task. You need to sit down with a guru (professor or TA, if you're in school) and go over the fundamentals of how MOSFETs work. This isn't something I can do within the Q&A format used here on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to produce the negative voltage. I took your advice about the proper switching voltage.